# Need to write all results to a txt file

Tags: c#, .net, powerbi, dax

I have the query below and it is working fine, I can see the results in the console. But I need to write all the result into a txt file to load it into a table. The query as is only write one line to the txt file. How can I make it write all lines from the output into the txt file? Really appreciate any help on this.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace PowerQry
{
    class Program
    {
#pragma warning disable IDE0060 // Remove unused parameter
        static void Main(string[] args)
#pragma warning restore IDE0060 // Remove unused parameter
        {

            AdomdConnection adomdConnection = new AdomdConnection("Data Source=localhost:49971");


            String query = @"
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    Customer[City],
    Customer[Country-Region],
    Customer[Customer],
    Customer[Customer ID],
    Customer[CustomerKey]
)
            ";
            AdomdCommand adomdCommand = new AdomdCommand(query, adomdConnection);

            /*******************************************************
                    connection
            *******************************************************/

            adomdConnection.Open();

            AdomdDataReader reader = adomdCommand.ExecuteReader();

            // Create a loop for every row in the resultset
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                String rowResults = "";
                // Create a loop for every column in the current row --need to add header
                for (
                    int columnNumber = 0;
                    columnNumber < reader.FieldCount;
                    columnNumber++
                    )
                {
                    rowResults += $"\t{reader.GetValue(columnNumber)}";
                }
                //Console.WriteLine(rowResults);
                //--write all lines to txt
                {
                    string UserName = System.Environment.UserName;
                    string fileName = @"C:\Temp\nm.txt";
                    FileStream ostrm;
                    StreamWriter writer;
                    TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;
                    try
                    {
                        ostrm = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                        writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm);
                        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Cannot open Redirect.txt for writing");
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                    Console.SetOut(writer);
                    Console.WriteLine(rowResults);
                    Console.SetOut(oldOut);
                    writer.Close();
                    ostrm.Close();
                     Console.WriteLine("Done");
                }
                //==
            }
            adomdConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "load it into a table" I assume you mean a database table. If that is the case, is there some reason you don't write directly to the database instead of to a file first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [File.AppendAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=net-5.0).

Instead of append to a single string instance you can use `List<string>`

```
//String rowResults = "";
List<string> rows = new List<string>();
// Create a loop for every column in the current row --need to add header
for (int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < reader.FieldCount;columnNumber++)
{
     // tabulator should be removed
     rows.Add($"\t{reader.GetValue(columnNumber)}");
     // rowResults += $"\t{reader.GetValue(columnNumber)}";
}

File.AppendAllLines(your path - for example @"C:\output.txt", rows);
```